# No Boxing Conversion from Derived to Base class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, compiler-errors

I'm trying to work through the following scenario. But have run across this compile time error.

```
The type 'DerivedDefinition' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'BaseInstance<T>'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'DerivedDefinition' to 'BaseDefinition'.
```

What is the cause and how can I resolve this?

This is related to a previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718509/supporting-generic-and-non-generic-implementation

UPDATE: This is the correct working code based on the provided answer below

```
public abstract class BaseDefinition 
{
    public virtual void Print() { Console.WriteLine("base definition"); }
}
public class DerivedDefinition : BaseDefinition 
{
    public override void Print() { Console.WriteLine("derived definition"); }
}


public abstract class BaseInstance
{
    protected BaseDefinition definition;
    public BaseDefinition Definition { get { return definition; } }
}

public abstract class BaseInstance<T> : BaseInstance where T : BaseDefinition
{
    //public T DefinitionExact { get { return (T)definition; } }
}

public class DerivedInstance : BaseInstance<DerivedDefinition>
{
    public DerivedInstance() 
    {
        definition = new DerivedDefinition();
    }
}


class TestClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BaseInstance baseInstance = new DerivedInstance();
        baseInstance.Definition.Print();
        //baseInstance.DefinitionExact.Print();

        DerivedInstance derivedInstance = new DerivedInstance();
        derivedInstance.Definition.Print();
    }
}
```

Code Below is very very wrong...

```
public abstract class BaseDefinition 
{
    public virtual string Print() { Console.WriteLine("base definition"); }
}
public class DerivedDefinition : BaseDefinition 
{
    public override string Print() { Console.WriteLine("derived definition"); }
}


public abstract class BaseInstance
{
    private BaseDefinition definition;
    protected BaseDefinition Definition { get { return definition; } }
}

public abstract class BaseInstance<T> : BaseInstance where T : BaseDefinition
{
    protected T DefinitionExact { get { return (T)definition; } }
}

public class DerivedInstance<DerivedDefinition> : BaseInstance<DerivedDefinition>
{
    public DerivedInstance() 
    {
        definition = new DerivedDefinition();
    }
}


class TestClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BaseInstance baseInstance = new DerivedInstance<DerivedDefinition>();
        baseInstance.Definition.Print();
        baseInstance.DefinitionExact.Print();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the compiler error, you need to constrain the type parameter in the derived class so it satisfies the constraint in the base class:

```
public class DerivedInstance<DerivedDefinition> : BaseInstance<DerivedDefinition>
    where DerivedDefinition : BaseDefinition
{
    public DerivedInstance() 
    {
        definition = new DerivedDefinition();
    }
}
```

However, since the name of your type parameter is the same as one of your class names, I suspect you actually meant to do this:

```
public class DerivedInstance : BaseInstance<DerivedDefinition>
{
    public DerivedInstance() 
    {
        definition = new DerivedDefinition();
    }
}
```

That is, the DerivedInstance class is perhaps intended not to be generic at all, but rather you intended to supply DerivedDefinition as the argument for the base class's type parameter.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed I made a number of mistakes in my example code, I'll replace it with the working variant.

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue with how you set up your generic:

```
    public class DerivedInstance<DerivedDefinition> : BaseInstance<DerivedDefinition>
{
    public DerivedInstance() 
    {
        definition = new DerivedDefinition();
    }
}
```

When you declare a Generic Class you put name in the <> that will be what type your class internally handles.  You want to replace  with  so your code looks like the following:

```
    public class DerivedInstance<T> : BaseInstance<T>
{
    public DerivedInstance() 
    {
        definition = new DerivedDefinition();
    }
}
```